# When does a user see a CakePHP 500 error page?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to know when a user will see the CakePHP 500 error page - *not* a true 500 Internal Server Error, just the CakePHP pretend 500 error page which is reserved for all 5xx HTTP error codes apparently.

It seems like most of the time, CakePHP will just show the 400 error page by default.

So what's the use of the 500 page, located at `View/Errors/erro500.ctp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing as nobody seems to know the answer to this, I will contribute to my own question.

By a stroke of luck, I happened to receive the 500 error page, and the reason was that the database was temporarily inaccessible on the server.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason, if the query goes wrong, like some fields name is misspelled or field does not exist and code is trying to access that field you get error 500 and this view View/Errors/erro500.ctp is used.